# Is there a benefit to Windows Amazon ECS vs EC2 auto-scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

For multiple high-volume .NET web applications running on Windows and IIS, is there any advantage to changing to CloudFormation and ECS or even EKS instead of just using an AMI of an instance that already has auto-run scripts to update the codebase and configuration on launch, tied into an auto-scaling group behind an ELB?

Our usage is to scale web application servers based on load.  Unless I have missed information or grossly misunderstood what has been read, it seems we might not gain anything by moving away from the pure AMI and auto-scaling group.

Answer (score 0):

@sivart Are you using containers? ECS and EKS are container orchestrators. These will benefit you if you package your web applications as docker containers.

CloudFormation helps stand up/down your infrastructure stack using IaC (infrastructure as code) and will help you spin up new infrastructures within minutes without clicking through the AWS console. This will help, for example, when you want to produce production comparable stack for you performance/load/QA before going live. You can create a stack, perform tests and destroy it once happy. You can integrate CloudFormation with your CI/CD pipelines.